# OrderedDict, UnboundLocalError: local variable 'link_next' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, ordereddict

TraceBack:

```
  File 'LRUCache.py', line 32, in get_value
  File 'lib\collections.py', line 157, in pop
  File 'lib\collections.py', line 88, in __delitem__
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'link_next' referenced before assignment
```

LRUCache.get

```
    try:
        value = self.cache.pop(key)
        self.cache[key] = value
        return value
    except KeyError:
        return None
```

Code in OrderedDict

```py
    def __delitem__(self, key, dict_delitem=dict.__delitem__):
        dict_delitem(self, key)
        link_prev, link_next, key = self.__map.pop(key)
        link_prev[1] = link_next
        link_next[0] = link_prev
```

And UnboundLocalError occured unexpectedly in last line.

it has no relation with closure.

I dont know why. beyond my imagination.

Comment: I don't believe this code will cause that error.  Please post the complete traceback.

Comment: traceback has been added. it's really unreasonable. Is there any undefined behavior or any unexpected memory error or any other unexpected thing will cause this error?

Comment: That is the Python 2.7 version of collections.py.  Are you actually using Python 2.7?  And you have not modified this file?